# Getting error on files.readAllLines

Tags: java, android, file.readalllines

I am working in android. For reading the file content, I am using the method

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(wiki_path);
```

But whem I am using this method I am getting this error:

> The method readAllLines(Path) is undefined for the type MediaStore.Files.

Why can the compiler not find the method?

```
Path wiki_path = Paths.get("C:/tutorial/wiki", "wiki.txt");

try {
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(wiki_path);
    for (String line : lines) {

        if(url.contains(line))
        {
            other.put(TAG_Title, name);
            other.put(TAG_URL, url);
            otherList.add(other);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Better you search 'how to read a file and store in list + android' may get the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [method you're trying to use](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-) is a member of [`java.nio.file.Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) - but that class (and indeed that package) doesn't exist on Android. Even if the Java 7 version existed, you're trying to use a method introduced in Java 8. The `Files` class you've imported is [`android.provider.MediaStore.Files`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Files.html) which is an entirely different class.

Even if it compiled, the path you're providing looks ever so much like a Windows path, which wouldn't work on an Android device...

Comment: @sheetal.gami: Well I'd *start* by making sure you can find the file and open an `InputStream` on it. You can then wrap that in an `InputStreamReader`, then wrap that in a `BufferedReader` and read that line by line. There may well be something appropriate in `android.util`, but I can't see anything immediately - go with the slightly clunkier code and get that working first.